# Can "pussy" be pronounced with /ʌ/ (uh)?

Tags: pronunciation

My friend insists it can be. Here is a [video](http://youtu.be/UZzScth3qno?t=19s) he provides as a proof (watch it cautiously, brain damage is possible). Is this nonsense or not? Maybe it is a *local* phenomenon? Or just a speech defect?

Answer (score 10):

Sure:  *pussy* in the sense of being “full of [*pus*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pus)” is pronounced with an /ʌ/, just like in *cut*, *putt*, *shun*, and *ton*.

The pussycat meaning of *pussy*, though, always has an /ʊ/ there, just like in *put*, *foot*, *look*, and *could*.